# Display data by week with week number

Tags: mysql

I am developing a script for hospital . In which i am facing problem in displaying data by week.

I am storing my data like this

```
nurse | ward | shift | sdate      | week 
  1   |   2  |  1st  | 2019-08-08 | 32
  1   |   3  |  2nd  | 2019-08-09 | 32
  1   |   3  |  1st  | 2019-08-10 | 32
  1   |   1  |  2nd  | 2019-08-12 | 33
  1   |   2  |  3rd  | 2019-08-13 | 33
  1   |   4  |  2nd  | 2019-08-15 | 33
  1   |   2  |  1st  | 2019-08-19 | 34
```

And i want to display it as

```
Week 32 
Ward  Shift  Date
2     1st    2019-08-08
3     2nd    2019-08-09
3     1st    2019-08-10   

Week 33
Ward  Shift   Date
2     2nd     2019-08-12
2     3rd     2019-08-13
4     2nd     2019-08-15    

Week 34
Ward  Shift  Date
2     1st    2019-08-19
```

I tried Using `Group By Week(sdate)` but it the display i am not getting as i want

Comment: Explain the logic for your desire output

Comment: For a particular Nurse , i want to display each week data

Comment: but what about shift and dates? can you expand the desire output. Right now you leave lot of blank space

Comment: have edited my post.

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza: hope its clear now

Answer (score 2):

```
What you can do is to order by your data on the basis of date.
```

Then in the script, you can try modifying the array in something like this format:

```
$arrData =
 [
  [0] =>[
         'nurse' => 1,
         'ward'  => 2,
         'shift' => '1st',
         'sdate' => '2019-08-08',
         'week'  => 32
        ],
  [1] =>[
         'nurse' => 1,
         'ward'  => 2,
         'shift' => '1st',
         'sdate' => '2019-08-08',
         'week'  => 33
        ]
]
```

Ordering by, is going to make sure that you will consistent weeks, i.e. after week 32 it will be week 33, and not 32 again.

The in the script what you might do is:

```
$intPrevShift = -1;
foreach($arrData as $arrDatum){
 if($arrDatum == $intPrevShift){
  // Keep doing stuff
 }
 else{
   echo 'Week: '. $arrDatum['week']
 }
 $intPrevShift = $arrDatum['week'];
}
```

Hope you got my point.

Comment: Yes, I will try this

Comment: Sure! Please don't forget to upvote if you find this helpful. Many Thanks!

Comment: @ATUL KUMAR SINGH,  Nice one, same concept can be used to do grouping till `n` level. Do highlight you first line which says `fetch data by ordering in week`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like **SELECT week, ward, shift, sdate as 'date' FROM nurse GROUP BY week, sdate;** ??

What are you trying and what do the results look like?